# не получается подключить mongo db к node js & express

Tags: node.js, mongo

пробую подключить mongodb к node js и в консоль выводится "(node:12832) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
d:\node\node_modules\mongoose\lib\mongoose.js:397
throw new MongooseError('Mongoose.prototype.connect() no longer accepts a callback');
^"

Comment: так написано же: `Mongoose.prototype.connect() no longer accepts a callback`, а у вас там колбек.

Comment: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/docs/migrating_to_7.md#dropped-callback-support

Comment: я исправил, но ошибка с устареванием все равно осталась, не могли бы вы прикрепить пример кода где вы создали сервер, и подключили mongodb к node js с помощью mongoose?

Comment: это не ошибка, а предупреждение. его можно игнорировать. а в mongoose 8.1 обещают убрать это предупреждение